# What is the best practice for firebase resending sendEmailVerification()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**My auth flow:**

Firebase `sendEmailVerification()` needs an already authenticated user to work as the first arg.
My auth flow at the moment works like this.

- Signing up the user with email and password `signUpWithEmailAndPassword()`
- Now the firebase `auth` object contains the `currentUser`
- Sending a verification mail to the just signed up user `sendEmailVerification()`
- Logging him out and redirecting him to `/email-verification` where he can send the verification mail again.

**Problem:**

Now the problem. When the user now wants to request to send the email verification again I have three options for what I know.

1. Store email and password in state before logging him out -> and then logging him in again on `sendAgain` and logging him out afterward. Would that be a security concern?
2. Let him logged in the whole time. Which doesn't feel too good as he wouldn't be able to log himself out again as he officially isn't signed in till he verifies his email.
3. Force him to input his email and password again every time he wants to send the verification mail again, which feels redundant and old school.

Answer (score 0):

If you require that the user verifies their email address in order to sign in, consider using the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) of Firebase Authentication.

> Let him logged in the whole time. Which doesn't feel too good as he wouldn't be able to log himself out again as **he officially isn't signed in till he verifies his email.**

This logic may apply to your application, but it is simply not how the email+password provider in Firebase Authentication works. When the user enters the correct credentials, they are signed in to Firebase Authentication. If your app requires them to have verified their email address before they can **use** it, that's the exact check I'd recommend implementing.

So if you want to continue using the email+password provider, reframe the statement to:

> In order to use the app, the user needs to sign in with their credentials and verify their email address.

You can then implement that in these two steps:

1. Ask them to sign in if they're not signed in already.
2. Then if the account doesn't have a verified email address, ask them to find the email and click the link - and give them to option to send another verification email.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I already know the `email link provider` but think that my users would prefer a password if possible. I'm not sure if you understand my problem correctly, my auth flow is as above written. This means they can be logged in and directly sending the verification mail or not and therefore have to provide the password and email again before resending the verification mail again. I'm only unsure about the best practice on how to handle it. What ways of my three outlined would you prefer or do you see another way of handling the user state? Details are in my question.

Comment: "therefore have to provide the password and email again before resending the verification mail again" That is only requires if you sign them out, which I see no reason to do. Hence my answer following up on your second approach. Why would the user need to enter their email/password again in this approach - especially when you provide an option to resend the email as I also answered (and is quite common in apps ("didn't receive our message? click here to send it again.")?

Comment: Hey @BenjaminK Anything else needed here?